# How might one create a Button that wraps everything hilghlighted with mouse with double quotes similar to Comment/Uncomment?

Tags: notebooks, string-manipulation, gui-construction, cells, button

I find typing doublequotes around characters to create strings a bit annoying because it always slows me down. The doublequotation marks lie right at my achilles heel on keyboards. It's too close to frequently used characters and symbols and my hand dexterity isnt what it used to be. But mouse actions almost never require much skill.

I envision it working with a `Button` or perhaps a `PasteButton` somehow but not sure. I know it might be done with a keyboard shortcut but it's almost as much work so I prefer a button solution. Again it should only directly create strings with doublequotes not `ToString`.

Im not asking anyone to code for me. Just asking for a starting point and direction to go. Thank you.

Comment: What is the keyboard shortcut for doing this?

Comment: @Domen lol yeah i know but sometimes when we reach a certain age the little tiny tasks become heavier because we lose dexterity or begin to have little aches in joints or we simply lose some physical skills due to aging. i can no longer type 60 wpm like i did in my 20's. im now almost 60 and can barely do about 25 wpm. the button i want to code is really for improving accessibility for me. it would fit on my `DockedCells` toolbar where i put my helper controls.

Comment: No no, I am seriously asking what is the keyboard shotcut for doing this (because I am not familiar with one) :)

Comment: @Domen i believe its shift-singlequote at start and end lol. im sure there may be macros one can download for creating shortcuts for wrapping quotes around characters to form strings for general use but im looking for an MMA solution. i dont use keyboard shortcuts all that much so i wouldnt know.